# Emacs recursive search/replace on Windows without Cygwin

Tags: replace, emacs, ide, emacs-projectile

To answer "where did I also use this identifier?" -questions, I run on macOS and the linuxes

```
dired-maybe-insert-subdir
dired-mark-files-regexp
```

followed by either of:

```
dired-do-find-regexp
dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace
```

On Windows I can get by using Emacs as my IDE *without* Cygwin, *except* for dired recursive search/replace.

Does [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile)
offer commands that will search/replace an identifier recursively *without* requiring Cygwin?

Does *any* other package make recursive search/replace possible on Windows without Cygwin?

I'm not concerned about the speed, because even after installing Cygwin, the recursive invocation of Cygwin's `grep` from within Emacs is painfully slow.

**Update:**

Recursive search/replace seems to be available in both
[Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm)
and
[Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile).

If true, then my question is:

1. Is the feature available on Windows without Cygwin?
2. The list of `require`s in my `.emacs` is already excessive. What is a light package that will do recursive search/replace (without Cygwin on Windows)?

**Clarification:**

OK. Success. [Thanks to Drew] With a `.emacs` containing nothing but `(require 'dired+)`, I can search-and-replace in marked files using `M-+ Q` on Windows **without** having Cygwin installed. I'm guessing that this will also work on linux/macOS, although perhaps not quite as quickly as delegating to `grep`. (The "Act on ALL files [] in and UNDER this dir?" confirmation message will start to get tedious, but that's a separate question.)

For the present question one issue needs clarification. `dired+` augments the built-in `dired` family of commands. Is there a way for it to take over ordinary `dired-do-find-regexp-and-replace`? That's because with the one-liner `.emacs`, and with a few marked files in a directory listing, I get

```
File not found - GREP
File not found - -I
...
File not found - NUL
File not found - ;
```

indicating that `grep` is still being invoked. How can tell `dired+` "I'm on Windows and I won't install Cygwin; please take over `A` and `Q`?" (mapped by default `dired-do-find-regexp` and the aforementioned command).

**Editorial**: `dired+` seems a bit overwhelming, but if it solves this one problem (eliminate the need for Cygwin on Windows), it will be well-worth figuring out how to move from the usual `dired` commands to `dired+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for a way to search files and get a list of those that match a regexp.  If `tags-query-replace` works for you on MS Windows (without Cygwin), and I think it should, then you can use command `diredp-do-query-replace-regexp-recursive`, bound to `M-+ Q` by default, available from [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus).

That acts on all marked files in the current Dired buffer, and on all marked files in all of the buffer's marked subdirs, and so on, recursively.

With a non-negative prefix arg it acts on all files in the current buffer and all files in all subdirs, and so on, recursively.  (That is, any marks are ignored, and the effect is as if everything were marked.)

---

If, instead of *finding* files that match a regexp, you want to search through files then you can use command `diredp-do-isearch-regexp-recursive`, bound to `M-+ M-s a C-M-` by default, also available from Dired+.  The files to access are defined similarly (all Dired+ `dired[p]-do...-recursive` commands act similarly wrt which files are identified to act on).  That definitely does not require any Cygwin etc. commands - it's just Isearch.